# Making sense of Inner-Join with Sub-query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables called '**table123**' and '**table246**'.

'**table123**' columns: '*ID*', '*Dept_ID*', '*First_Name*', '*Surname*', '*Salary*', '*Address*'.

'**table246**' columns: '*Dept_ID*', '*Dept_Name*'.

I want to find the Average Salary for each '*Dept_Name*'. So I tried using the query below, which is an Equi-Join with a Sub-query:

```
SELECT Dept_Name, alt.Average_Salary AS Avg_Salary
FROM table123 a, table246 b,
(SELECT Dept_ID, AVG(Salary)Avg_Salary
FROM table123
GROUP BY Dept_ID)alt
WHERE a.Dept_ID = alt.Dept_ID
AND a.Salary = alt.Average_Salary
AND a.Dept_ID = b.Dept_ID;
```

However, when I run the above query, it gives the desired 2 column names '*Dept_Name*' and '*Avg_Salary*', but with no data in it (just a blank table).

What am I doing wrong in the code, which is causing this blank result table?

Also, is there an alternative method of getting the same result, using an Inner- Join? The Equi-Join is quite confusing.

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The link above details a problem linked with this question.

Comment: It gives me what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Your query does not return results because no one has *exactly* the average value, so the salary condition fails.  Based on what you are selecting, the subquery is the query you want:

```
SELECT Dept_ID, AVG(Salary) as Avg_Salary
FROM table123
GROUP BY Dept_ID;
```

Presumably, the other table brings in the name, so:

```
SELECT b.Dept_Name, AVG(a.Salary) as Avg_Salary
FROM table123 a JOIN
     table246 b
     ON a.Dept_ID = b.Dept_Id
GROUP BY b.Dept_Name;
```

Comment: can you give the ans of this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42998768/2286537

Comment: So, do I combine the two queries?

Comment: @J.I . . . `JOIN` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`.  Once upon a time, the standard did not support outer joins, so the only syntax was `JOIN`.  Many people still use the shorter form.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So, I can use whichever form? And by the way, do both the Equi-Join and Inner-Join statements give me the same result-set?

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
SELECT Dept_Name, alt.Avg_Salary  
FROM table246 b
INNER JOIN (SELECT Dept_ID, AVG(Salary)Avg_Salary
            FROM table123
            GROUP BY Dept_ID)alt ON B.DEPT_ID = ALT.DEPT_ID
```

Comment: That gives what I wanted, but I had to modify your answer. In the first line, it should be alt.Avg_Salary to get the correct result. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, corrected.  Give your preference to the answer if you found it usefult.

Comment: what are you speaking about?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go through this maybe it will help you.

   http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3835506/Fetching-Data-from-Multiple-Tables-using-Joins.htm